# How to prove that $\log \log n/ \log n$ goes to zero with almost elementary techniques?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

I am trying to show that:

$$ \lim_n \frac{\log \log n}{\log n} = 0 $$

without using "advanced" calculus techniques (derivatives, analysis of the function $x \mapsto \log \log x/ \log x$...). I was able to show that the sequence

$$ n \mapsto \log n / n $$

is monotone decreasing, but this does not seem to trivially imply that $n \mapsto \log \log n / \log n$ is also monotone decreasing. Is there any way around this? Once monotonicity is proven, one can argue that $\log \log n / \log n$ is positive and eventually smaller than every (positive) number and/or find a suitable subsequence converging to zero. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would L'Hospital be considered too advanced?

Comment: How did you show that $\log(n)/n$ is monotone decreasing without "advanced" calculus techniques?

Comment: If you write down the difference of two consecutive terms, after some computations you see that it suffices to show that $(1+1/n)^{1/n} < n$ for sufficiently large $n$. This can be done via Newton binomial theorem and/or the fact that $n \mapsto (1+1/n)^n $ is monotone increasing and converges to a number less or equal than 3. I would say this is rather elementary, isn't it ?

Comment: There is a typo in the previous comment: $(1+1/n)^n < n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(\log x)/x$ and $g(x)=\log x$. Then $(\log\log x)/\log x = f(g(x))$ is the composition of a decreasing function and an increasing function; and such a composition is automatically decreasing.

Comment: I was explicitly asking to avoid the analysis of the corresponding real function... see also my first comment below the post as an example of what I mean with "elementary techniques"!

Comment: I encourage you to think about the steps required to carry out your comment, and realize that you are using facts at least as "advanced" as saying that the composition of monotone functions is monotone.